# CSS OpenType: How to replace a single letter in entire text with character from Stylistic Set 1 without affecting other letters?

Tags: css, typography, opentype

**Would like to achieve:**
We would like to replace the double-story lowercase "g" with the single-story version in our entire website text.

[image]

**Problem:**
Our font [Rotunda](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/rotunda-variable) ([TipoType Foundry link](https://tipotype.com/rotunda/)) has a Stylistic Set 1 which contains also other alternate characters. However, we only would like to change the lowercase g and not affect any other letters.
[image]

**Leads:**
There some CSS OpenType features which seem to allow to replace only a single letter, but we were unable to get it to work. We found [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/csshelp/comments/157dgzu/csshelp_access_single_character_in_an_opentype/) which lists the same issue and a user posted this solution:

> If your font only has one stylistic set, ss01, and you want to change only the lowercase "g" out of the ss01 set, you can use the font-variant-alternates property in CSS. This property allows you to access alternate glyphs in a font.
>
> You can use the following CSS code to access the alternate "g" in the ss01 set:
>
> selector { font-variant-alternates: "ss01" 1; }
>
> You can replace selector with the selector for the element you want to apply the style to. The "ss01" value refers to the ss01 stylistic set of the font. The 1 value refers to the index of the alternate "g" glyph in the ss01 set.

However, we are unsure how to find the actual index number of the lowercase "g".

Another resource is [this](https://www.jonathan-harrell.com/blog/better-typography-with-font-variants/#font-variant-alternates), which recommends to use "font-variant-alternates" (stylistic(feature-value-name)), but again they seem to target letter via selectors like "inscriptional-g". We don't know this selector of lowercase in the Rotunda font.

Our feeling is that this can be achieved with the [font-variant-alternates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-alternates) parameter, but we are unable to put the correct CSS together.

---

We successfully tried a Javascript option to add a span tag around all instances of the lowercase "g" and target the character this way. But it seems inefficient and there's also a short "flash" when the character is replaced on the page. We are looking for a safe cross-browser (CSS) solution to achieve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841844/font-face-unicode-range-attribute

Answer (score 0):

You *may* be able to apply an alternate style sets via [`@font-feature-values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_fonts/OpenType_fonts_guide#alternates) or `font-feature-settings`.

In the example below using "IBM Plex Serif" we can replace all "g" occurrences with alternate glyphs by selecting the `ss02` style set – without replacing "a" occurrences.
This only works because the font provides a set for all "g" alternate glyphs (including g-diacritics).

In other word: we can't actually target/replace single glyphs. If your font only includes a set with all alternates – all glyphs from this set will be replaced (i.e "a" and "g"). In this case wrapping all "g" occurences is your only chance.

#### Inspecting stylistic sets

These style sets are not standardised and vary between different fonts - so you may need to select a different style set, e.g. `ss01`.
You can inspect all alternate features with the tool [wakamai fondue](https://wakamaifondue.com/) to find the desired stylistic set.

[image: opentype features wakamai fondue]

```css
@font-face{
  font-family: 'Plex Serif';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src : url('https://mdn.github.io/css-examples/font-features/fonts/plex/IBMPlexSerif-Regular.woff')
}

body{
font-family: 'Plex Serif';
font-size:10vmin;
}

@font-feature-values "Plex Serif" {
  @styleset { alt-a: 1; alt-g: 2; }
}

.alt-g{
  font-variant-alternates: styleset(alt-g);
}

.alt-g2{
  font-feature-settings: 'ss02' 1;
}

.alt-a{
  font-variant-alternates: styleset(alt-a);
}

.alt-a2{
  font-feature-settings: 'ss01' 1;
}
```

```html
<p class="">Hamburg (all standard)</p>

<h3>@font-feature-values</h3>
<p class="alt-a">Hamburg (a alt)</p>
<p class="alt-g">Hamburg (g alt)</p>

<h3>font-feature-settings</h3>
<p class="alt-a2">Hamburg (a alt)</p>
<p class="alt-g2">Hamburg (g alt)</p>
```

Comment: Note that this would still require tagging each `g` with its own span or the like, because otherwise every other letter that also has a counterpart in the chosen stylistic set will get replaced as well. And unfortunately, tagging individual letters will almost certainly "break" gpos/gsub rules.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! In the above example based on the IBM Plex it actually works – albeit we are just lucky the font provides a set that suits our needs. Updated the answer to emphasize this point.